# Can a stateful React Context Provider increase the number of re-renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Imagine a Stateful Context Provider like this one:

```
const CurrentUserContext = React.createContext(null);

export default CurrentUserContext;

export function CurrentUserProvider(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useStateWithCallback(null);

  return (
    <CurrentUserContext.Provider value={{ data, setData }}>
      {props.children}
    </CurrentUserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

and a HOC for consuming it:

```
import { CurrentUserContext } from "../../context";

const withCurrentUser = (Component) => (props) => (
  <CurrentUserContext.Consumer>
    {(currentUser) => <Component {...props} currentUser={currentUser} />}
  </CurrentUserContext.Consumer>
);

export default withCurrentUser;
```

In my situation I have a screen called "Profile" which renders the current user's data (his avatar in a custom component called "Header", and some text (also relative to his data) in the default React Native's "Text" component).

> ProfileScreen [Parent] ---> Header [Child]

As this "Header" component is only used in this screen, I have thought to do:

```
 export default withCurrentUser(Header)
```

so, I don't have to pass the current user's data as prop from the Profile screen (which is also wrapped with this HOC).

> withCurrentUser(ProfileScreen) [Parent] ---> withCurrentUser(Header) [Child]

Now, imagine that a random node of the full components tree updates this Context Provider's state... Here is where my question comes. Is there any chance of making an unnecessary re-render with the situation I have described? I mean, can it be possible that the Header custom component re-renders before the Profile screen, and then, when the Profile screen re-renders, its child (the Header) re-renders too again? Or will everything be rendered in sequence?

I am asking this because I am not sure about if this would be better to pass the user data from the "Profile" screen to all its children components that requires it, having a single Context Consumer, or to have multiple Context Consumers (the screen and all its children that requires the user data) and ignore passing the data as prop.

Comment: Why you use HOC when you can use custom hooks?...

Comment: I also have class components which want to use this functionality. That is why I implemented this as a HOC. Anyways, my react level is not professional enough, maybe custom hooks can be used in class components. But as I understand, by definition, hooks are associated with functional components.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is if it’s one level pass it as a props, don’t try to think of a fancy way. For your question, yes you can I increase updates by updating the props or if you have a reducer dispatching actions. Fortunately the context API rerenders all views, you can check an examppe they have here and compare

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/01/introduction-react-context-api/

If you are using React Hooks you should write your USE STATE

like const [foo, setFoo] = useState(() => bar)

This will only run on mounted. If your subscribing make sure to unsubscribe. Hope this helps. To keep state updating make sure to update the state with the respected const.